# Stacked plot with spaced xticks

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, group-by, xticks

I have done an aggregation which resulted in the following dataframe

```
df2 = tweet.groupby(['Realdate', 'Type'])['Text'].count().unstack().fillna(0)

Type           BLM   Black
Realdate                  
2020-03-01    21.0     9.0
2020-03-02    20.0    13.0
2020-03-03    32.0    16.0
2020-03-04     3.0     9.0
2020-03-05    28.0    16.0
...            ...     ...
2020-07-10  4050.0  4474.0
2020-07-11  2815.0  3743.0
2020-07-12  3575.0  3863.0
2020-07-13  3435.0  4704.0
2020-07-14  3284.0  4352.0
```

I then created a stacked plot as follows:

```
df2[['BLM','Black']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(20,10))
```

The output is:

[image]

I have too many days and i am struggling to space the xticks. Can someone help me please?
I was tempted to replace my xticks and generate new ones but i have been unsuccessful so far.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found this answer

```
sum_df=tweet.groupby(['Realdate', 'Type'])['Text'].count().unstack().fillna(0)
sum_df=sum_df.reset_index()
print(sum_df)
    

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))    
ax1.set_xlabel('Dates')    
ax1.set_ylabel('# of Tweets', color='b')    
ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
sum_df[['Black', 'BLM']].plot( kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax1, figsize=(20,10))     
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)       
ax1.set_xticklabels(sum_df.Realdate, rotation=90)    
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)    
plt.legend(['#BlackLivesMatter', '#BLM'])
plt.title('# of Tweets per Day')
plt.show()
```

[image]